# Map one controller action on another action rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, nested-routes, custom-routes

I have a controller named `carts_controller` and in my routes I am using restful routes i.e., `resources :carts`.

I know resources create default actions like create, index etc., but if I don't want to user create and create a method `add_to_cart` and in routes I have defined its route as

```
post '/add_cart/:product_id/' => 'carts#add_to_cart', as: 'add_to_cart'
```

Does this route considered RESTFUL?

I don't want to user all the default `RESTFUL` routes created by resources. I want some custom actions in place of these. My code is working but I am confused as my concepts are not clear. Another thing is if I know that I need `product_id` in my routes, should I make them nested inside products resources or it will work if I define custom ad I defined  above?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What does `add_to_cart` do, exactly? Does it create a new resource or update a resource? If so, what resource does it create/update?

Comment: `add_to_cart` check if user has any cart or not. If not then it creates new cart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your current approach is fine. Not all controller actions will fit nicely into the standard CREATE/UPDATE/DESTROY actions. It's also pretty obvious what `add_to_cart` does.

As an alternative you could consider doing this in the `update` action of the cart controller. If a `cart` has many `products` you could consider using nested params:

```
params: {
  cart: {
    products_attributes: [{
      "0" => { ...product_attributes_here.. }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```